# JSLink in List View when rendered as web part

Tags: jslink

I have implemented some custom formatting using the SharePoint 2013 JSLink functionality for a custom list, but noticed the formatting is not applied when the list is added to a wiki page as a web part.  I assumed that if I added the JSLink attribute to the list's view then it would be loaded whenever that view is used, but it appears not.

Is this the expected behavior, and if so, is there any way to have a custom list always render in the same way, even if it is embedded as a web part?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS Link is a Javascript Linking to the webpart. Even in a List View from the Site contents is nothing more than another webpart. When you add the JS to that view it is only added to that view. When you place a new webpart at a new location you must give the new webpart the JS Link again.

If you wish to make it such that default view has the JS linked you must add that JS script to the aspx code of the view in sharepoint designer.

Comment: Thanks.  Every time I try playing with the aspx code everything seems to break (and I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything totally stupid!).

Comment: It breaks depending on what you are trying to do. Let me know if you have any specific error that I can look at and might be able to help.